# Origin error when using postMessage from parent to iframe (Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, iframe, message

I'm trying to make two React Apps communicate by sending messages containing stringified objects.

The parent (http://localhost:3000) sends a message through `postMessage` like so:

```js
    let iframe = document.querySelector("iframe")

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!!localStorageObject && !!iframe) {
            iframe?.contentWindow?.postMessage(localStorageObject, "http://localhost:3001")
        }
    }, [localStorageObject, iframe])

    // ...file and start of return

   <iframe
       style={{minHeight: window.outerHeight, width: '100%', border: "none"}}
       referrerPolicy="strict-origin-when-cross-origin"
       src={myUrlWithParams}
       title="App"
       allow="clipboard-write"
       id={"iframe"}
   />
```

The iFrame (http://localhost:3001) does not recieve the message, at least not immediatly (I have to wait for a react soft refresh for the logs to show up).

The error thrown at first is:

```
Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('http://localhost:3001') does not match the recipient window's origin ('http://localhost:3000').
```

Comment: This seems very hacky, why do you need 2 apps to comunicate by iframes, couldn't it just be a single app?

Answer (score 0):

This is because your iframe document hasn't loaded yet when you call this `postMessage()` method, and hence the `contentWindow` you receive is the one of the original `about:blank` document, not your expected one.

One could argue that the error message is a bit confusing here, and your dev tools could probably have been nicer by (also?) reporting that the location's origin was `about:blank` (even if it's the global document's `origin` that's been checked for `postMessage()`).

But anyway, to workaround that issue, wait for the `load` event of your `<iframe>`. (I'm sorry I'm not a reactJS ninja, so I'll let you the work of finding the best way to do so).

Here is a vanilla repro setup with the solution applied: https://jsfiddle.net/382pz5er/ (outsourced because StackSnippet's null origined frames make for a bad example here).